# Do the same energies live in Graveyard (Kabristaan) and Cremation Grounds (Shamshaan Ghaat) or are they different?

Tags: shiva, shaivism, shakti, shaktism

Like Bhoot, Pret, **MASAAN** and other beings?

What about dead bodies there? Do they have different energies?

Comment: Question is a bit unclear. Could you please elaborate on what exactly you want to ask?